# Treeview with checkboxes and a list box

Tags: wpf, listbox, treeview

I have a tree view with checkboxes bounded to a property by name Ischecked in the corresponding view model,and whose content will be loaded on demand.Now when ever user checks the box,in the Ischecked setter property I add the checked treeview item into another Generic List(When a node is unchecked,It is removed from the List).Now I have two buttons namely select and deselect button.So when user checks different nodes and press select I will update the List box in the same usercontrol with the Generic List that I had previously.
How do I uncheck the corresponing treeview Items when user wants to remove few items from List box.Also am I doing the right way?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView can help you.